# JTable Cell Font? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtable

The program I am creating *should* work like `Microsoft Excel`, except in `JAVA`. It *should* also support cell formatting (Which is my problem). I have the code for detecting which cell is clicked, and what font to use working properly - I just **can not** figure out how to apply the `Font` to the cell! `Google` gave me `CellRenderers`, but it seems that cell renderers format the cell only when a condition is `true`. I want it to format with the specified `Font` it when it is called!

Can someone ***please*** help me, I am ***really confused***!!!

I have already looked at the [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

My apologies if this question has been asked before!

Comment: Here's an article that may help - [Set the JTable](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-09/03-qa-0928-jtable.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is what you are looking for,, this code snippet changes the font of all columns in a jTable..
I'm sure a slight modification should get your scenario covered.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getColumnCount(); i ++) {
    TableColumn col = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
    col.setCellEditor(new MyTableCellEditor());
}


public class MyTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
    JComponent component = new JTextField();
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
        ((JTextField)component).setText((String)value);
        ((JTextField)component).setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Unicode MS", 0, 12));
        return component;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change the font for all cells in the table - even when new columns or rows are added:

```
JTable table;
......
Object dce = table.getDefaultEditor(Object.class);
if(dce instanceof DefaultCellEditor) {
    ((DefaultCellEditor) dce).getComponent().setFont([your font]);
}
```