# Change preview font in table?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtable

In my program I implemented a table, I recently found out how to change the font size of the table so this is what I did: 
It sets the font of the contents in the table to 20, however before I confirm an input with enter or select another cell, the preview is still the standard font and too small

```
table.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
```

The preview should also be the same size, that's what I wanna do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is modify the Default Cell Editor like this:

```
Object dce = jTable1.getDefaultEditor(Object.class);
if(dce instanceof DefaultCellEditor) {
    Font font = new Font(jTable1.getFont().getName(), jTable1.getFont().getStyle(), 20);  // 20 is your desired font size
    ((DefaultCellEditor) dce).getComponent().setFont(font);
}
```

This concept was retrieved from this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46334623/4725875) by @Redwine.